# GridView get row and Column

Tags: android, gridview

Is that any way to get the row and column number of the clicked cell in GridView (Android)?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {   
            int row_no=position/MAX_COL;
            int col_no=position%MAX_COL;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected" + "ID" + id, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

I'm using this but is there any way to directly get the row, col no

Comment: NO there is no direct way of getting it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns()